# Split a string between repeating characters

Tags: java, regex, split

I want to take any given string and split it based on repeating characters.

As an example, if I were to input the string `abcaaabbc`, I would want to output an array of strings equal to: `[abca, a, ab, bc]`. Each time a character repeats, I want to start a new string.

Doing this with a loop is possible, of course, but I am wondering if I can achieve it using the `String.split()` method. If so - what would the `RegEx` be?

Comment: Can't understand your question. Can you give some other example?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tokenize the input string where previous character(look-behind `(?<=(.))`) is same as next character(look-ahead `(?=\\1)`) and `\1` captures `(.)`.

```
    String str = "abcbabaaabbc";
    String regex = "(?<=(.))(?=\\1)";        
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split(regex)));
```

Comment: @SwapnilS: Tokenize the string where previous character(look behind `(?<=)`) is same as next character(look ahead `(?=)`). and `\1` captures `(.)`

Answer (score 0):

From a performance perspective, I would stick with a loop.  It runs in O(n) time.  The string.split(regex) has been known to be slow.  I recently used it in place of a loop and found that it was O(n^2) compared to the O(n) loop.

K.I.S.S principal works here